# Create Android Selector in code

Tags: android

I have a drawable called "XYZ"

```
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="@color/highlightpen_blue" />

        <padding android:bottom="7dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="7dp" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

in a button
android:background="@drawable/XYZ"

i just want to create XYZ in code purely to change @color/highlightpen_blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Fahim's answer,but some difference.

```
StateListDrawable states = (StateListDrawable) btn.getBackground();
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) states.getCurrent();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the of GradientDrawable

```
GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) titleTextView.getBackground();
 background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color))
```

Comment: thanks but it should not work because the Background is not a GradientDrawable, but Selector. I actually want the button with some solid color with round corner

Comment: @DayDayHappy this will change the color of <shape> tag in the xml at runtime and it will keep the round corner, what you are doing in the xml